# Cloud EndPoint GRPC dont match proto definition

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, protocol-buffers, google-cloud-endpoints, grpc

I'm using Google Cloud EndPoints to access my GRPC server written in GoLang that run in Kuberkules. I was following the tutorial for [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/configure-endpoints). Everythings is working but when i try to the a request i got this error

rpc error: code = NotFound desc = Method does not exist.

The EndPoint does not have the save URL has the one in my proto file , the have the package include in the name. Here is an exemple :

[log request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeGV3.png)

on the last request i change the value of the url in the generated protobuf file, it pass the endpoint but my server dont recognize it ... I got this error instead :

```
rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service client.WebRoute
```

[protobuf generated code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgVEp.png)

It was working locally , this is probably an issue about the descriptor files needed to generate the endpoints.

Comment: Can you post your proto file? And to clarify, what you're saying is that Endpoints only recognizes client.WebRoute. The expectation is that it should just be WebRoute?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the URL in the generated file. gRPC spec defines the HTTP path is 
`Service-Name "/" {method name}`. The Service-Name for protobuf is `?( {proto package name} "." ) {service name}`. You can change your proto file and regenerate the descriptors and your Go code to match what path you want.